# Where can I find Aptana error logs?

Tags: logs, java

Where are Aptana error logs stored in fedora?I want them to see why Aptana crashes.

Edit: According to Mat's answer I checked the .log file in .metadata directory but this is what Is added to file after crash, which doesn't contain any helpful information to find what's causing the crash.

```
!SESSION 2011-10-07 15:03:51.721 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.6.0_22
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86, WS=gtk, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.resources 2 10035 2011-10-07 15:03:52.870
!MESSAGE The workspace exited with unsaved changes in the previous session; refreshing workspace to recover changes.
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [Accessing the Log File](http://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/tis/Accessing+the+Log+File), the Apatana log file is in a subdirectory of your workspace (`.metadata/.log`).

There is no centralized Java log directory, each application pretty much has its own logging habits.

Comment: When Aptana crashes, the .log file doesn't change. Is there anywhere else to find logs?

Comment: I don't know. Are you sure you're looking at the right directory? No permission issues on the dir or files?